# How do I get more than 1000 message records from Twilio using Python

Tags: python, json, twilio

My message object has more than 1000 records.

In my code I am looping through and picking out records from a specific "Sent From" phone number. I get records back and I display the sent from and receiver phone numbers and an index number to make counting the number of records returned easier.

I know there are more than 1000 records but it stops at 1000. How can I get more records?

I have been working with Twilio support and they sent me here to ask because they are not Python versed.

Here is the code I have now (I of course took out sensitive account info):

```
import requests
import json
r = requests.get('https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AccountSID/Messages.json?DateSent=2017-09-28&From=PhoneNumber&PageSize=10000', auth=('AccountSID', 'AuthToken'))
json_parsed = json.loads(r.text)
var = 0
var2 = 0
while var < 10000:
    var1 = var
    if (json_parsed['messages'][var1]['from']) == "+PhoneNumber":
        print "From:" + " " + json_parsed['messages'][var1]['from']
        print "To::" + " " +json_parsed['messages'][var1]['to']
        print "\n"
        vartotal = var1 + 1
        print vartotal

    var = var1 + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio REST API limits the amount of records you can return. You need to use pagination. The key variables are [in the Twilio Paging documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/response#response-formats-list-paging-information), but it just involves adding a`Page` parameter to the URL.

So you would get back pages of 1,000. If exactly 1,000 are returned, process and request the next page. If less than 1,000 are returned, break out of the loop.

You can also look for the `nextpageuri` returned in the JSON. If there, follow it.

Comment: The `Page` parameter is deprecated (if not already removed) so you should absolutely looks for the [`next_page_uri` property in the JSON](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/response#response-formats-list-filters).

Comment: I can see the nextpageuri at the end of the JSON object, it is similar to the original URI. While the pagination is depricated I have not found much on how to call the next page. The nextpageuri must be handled differently than the original and called differently. I am working on that now.

Comment: One more thing now that I got this working, the next page uri havs a Page Token in it. The next page uri will be the same as the original one with &PageToken=TokenNumber added to the uri, To get this page token you need to get the next page uri at the bottom of the json return from the original request (nextpage = json_parsed['next_page_uri']) and then resubmit. Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This is your code but written properly:

```
import requests
import json
r = requests.get('https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AccountSID/Messages.json?DateSent=2017-09-28&From=PhoneNumber&PageSize=10000', auth=('AccountSID', 'AuthToken'))
for i, message in enumerate(json.loads(r.text)['messages']):
    if message['from'] == "+PhoneNumber":
        print "From: {}".format(message['from'])
        print "To: {}".format(message['to'])
        print
        print i + 1
```

Use a `for` loop and let it handle the counter variables and to iterate over the full ammount of messages that you request. Use `"".format()` to format strings.

The problem that you are encountering is that you are requesting 10000 messages: ('https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AccountSID/Messages.json?DateSent=2017-09-28&From=PhoneNumber&PageSize=10000') How Twilio API works is out of my knowledge, but it may be having a maximum value for this setting and you are unable to fetch that much. If this is true they will have some sort of pagening settings that allow you to get the next X messages, probably by specifying the message where to start and the ammount you want.

Comment: Thank you for this.